# Reading all channels MCP3008

Tags: python, pi-3, i2c, spi, analog-to-digital

I have a problem with reading data from adc convertor MCP3008 10bit.

I found a python script from adafruit that give data value from all channels
(CHO TO CH7). I added a picture with my results and the from adafruit site
"https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/30459".

You can see that mine results are jumping while from the adafruit is stable on zero. So I think there is something wrong with some of one configuration file.

Any help would be appreciate

```
# Simple example of reading the MCP3008 analog input channels and printing
# them all out.
# Author: Tony DiCola
# License: Public Domain
import time

# Import SPI library (for hardware SPI) and MCP3008 library.
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MCP3008

# Hardware SPI configuration:
SPI_PORT   = 0
SPI_DEVICE = 0
mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE))


print('Reading MCP3008 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')
# Print nice channel column headers.
print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*range(8)))
print('-' * 57)
# Main program loop.
while True:
    # Read all the ADC channel values in a list.
    values = [0]*8
    for i in range(8):
        # The read_adc function will get the value of the specified channel (0-7).
        values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)
    # Print the ADC values.
    print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*values))
    # Pause for half a second.
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong when a pin is unconnected it is called floating and can have any value between 0 and 1023 in this case. Evidence for this is when you connect 3.3 volts on channel 0 you get 1023 constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Steve,

I checked, and indeed when I connect at voltage between 0 to 3.3v the value are stable.
But now I have a other problem.
I have (found) a python script to read the adc value.
I get a value around 303 by a voltage of 1.552. When calculating it should be
1.552V*(4096/3.3V)=1926.

## !/usr/bin/python3

import spidev
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
channel = 1
result = spi.xfer2([1, 8 + channel << 4, 0])
adcValue = ((result[1] & 15) << 8) + result[2]
print(adcValue)
spi.close()

Running this script the adc value is correct.
The most scipts I found are like the one above.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

#

## MCP3204/MCP3208 sample program for Raspberry Pi

#

## how to setup /dev/spidev?.?

## $ suod modprobe spi_bcm2708

#

## how to setup spidev

## $ sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip

## $ sudo pip install spidev

#
import spidev
import time

class MCP3208:
        def **init**(self, spi_channel=0):
                self.spi_channel = spi_channel
                self.conn = spidev.SpiDev(0, spi_channel)

## self.conn.max_speed_hz = 1000000 # 1MHz

```
            self.conn.max_speed_hz = 1 # 1Hz

    def __del__( self ):
            self.close

    def close(self):
            if self.conn != None:
                    self.conn.close
                    self.conn = None

    def bitstring(self, n):
            s = bin(n)[2:]
            return '0'*(8-len(s)) + s

    def read(self, adc_channel=0):
            # build command
            cmd  = 128 # start bit
            cmd +=  64 # single end / diff
            if adc_channel % 2 == 1:
                    cmd += 8
            if (adc_channel/2) % 2 == 1:
                    cmd += 16
            if (adc_channel/4) % 2 == 1:
                    cmd += 32

            # send & receive data
            reply_bytes = self.conn.xfer2([cmd, 0, 0, 0])

            #
            reply_bitstring = ''.join(self.bitstring(n) for n in reply_bytes)
            # print reply_bitstring

            # see also... http://akizukidenshi.com/download/MCP3204.pdf (page.20)
            reply = reply_bitstring[5:19]
            return int(reply, 2)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
        spi = MCP3208(0)

```
    count = 0
    a0 = 0
    a1 = 0
    a2 = 0
    a3 = 0

    while True:
            count += 1
            a0 += spi.read(0)
            a1 += spi.read(1)
            a2 += spi.read(2)
            a3 += spi.read(3)

            if count == 10:
```

## print "ch0=%04d, ch1=%04d, ch2=%04d, ch3=%04d" % (a0/10, a1/10, a2/10, a3/10)

```
                    print (a0/10)
                    count = 0
                    a0 = 0
                    a1 = 0
                    a2 = 0
                    a3 = 0
```